# Radio Button to Function as Conditional with simple_form in Rails, Not Persisted to the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Currently I do not know how to create a radio button with simple_form that is not an attribute of a resource.

I am trying to create a radio button that is not saved to the database.  The radio button simply functions as a conditional:  If the `yes` radio button is checked, then I will add in some stuff with coffeescript.  If `no` is selected then nothing should happen.

code so far:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@model) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Were you referred here?" %>
    <div>
        <%= f.radio_button :referral_check%> Yes
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.radio_button :referral_check%> No
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way I could find to do it:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@model) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label "Were you referred here?" %>
   <div>
       <%= radio_button_tag "referral", "true" %> Yes 
   </div>
   <div>
       <%= radio_button_tag "referral", "false" %> No 
   </div>
<% end %>
```

The attribute of `referral` does not need to exist as an attribute to any model. In other words, there is no column in any of the database tables named `referral`. This *attribute* will still get passed to the server with all the other parameters, but that is ok.  Thanks to strong parameters, and the fact that I used a `radio_button_tag` thus not tieing this input selection to the current form, Nothing will happen with this *attribute*.  Once it gets to the server it will simply be ignored.